# PHP Socket: Simple TCP Proxy

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

My goal is to make a simple TCP proxy application for my test lab. I want to modify some JSON data on the fly. I successfully managed to work a TCP client, and a TCP server, but individually, not at once.

Basically I want a PHP with 2 sockets, one for incoming clients, one for outgoing to server, and forward data to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Socket Programming With PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/) and [An Introduction to Sockets in PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/An-Introduction-to-Sockets-in-PHP/).

Both of those look like very good tutorials, in fact the first one appears to both recieve and send data.

EDIT: added [Writing Socket Servers in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/) as that was the link that helped the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already looket at first tutorial, and now the second one. The fact, it does not involve client and server socket at the same time. Individually i succesfully wrote my app in client and server modes, but i need to bind a server socket, accept that connection, another socket that connects to a remote server. And when the client socket receives data, the server socket sends towards to server. And the reply from the server socket goes to client socket. I hope you got it :) Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to write this as a webpage, or as a command line? Sockets really don't work well with web pages because the server WILL close the connection on you after a bit.

Is [Writing Socket Servers in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086#Heading7) more what you need?

Comment: Of course, i have installed PHP 5.3 only, and running as a command line application :)

Comment: I missed the link in your comment. It's good for server well, but i need to implement a client too :) I tried before but data isnt tunnelled well though.

Comment: I tried to do with the tutorials, but the last one (Writing Socket Server in PHP) fails with error even with 1:1 copied code. Anyone who willing to help will greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, Drazisil. With your tutorial i managed to get it work.